# Swing Panels Color Change

Tags: java, swing, events, jpanel, awt

I am trying to launch multiple JFrames with a custom panel that I created called `subpanel`. [In case you are wondering about the naming, I have another class called `masterpanel`, which contains a button that launches a new frame containing a new instance of `subpanel`.

The purpose of the `subpanel` is that when the user hits the `enter` button, the color changes. Currently, I have each `subpanel` contain an inner class called `EnterAction`, which calls `setBackground` to change the color.

I was wondering how I can modify this so that I can synchronize the color change between all of my `subpanels`.

Currently, I have a variable `green`, which I believe I can pass between all of my panels. However, I'm not sure how I can get the `EnterAction` to change all of the currently active panels?

I was thinking of creating a list of active `subpanels`? But will this cause an additional problem that I would need to maintain the list if the user closes a `subpanel`?

Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.Action;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;

public class SubPanel extends javax.swing.JPanel
{   
    private Action enterAction;

    public SubPanel() 
    {
        initComponents();
        enterAction = new EnterAction();

            //KeyBindings on the enter button
        this.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke( "ENTER" ), "doEnterAction");
        this.getActionMap().put( "doEnterAction", enterAction );
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        setForeground(new java.awt.Color(1, 1, 1));
        setToolTipText("");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(this);
        this.setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 300, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
    }// </editor-fold>                        
    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    // End of variables declaration                   

    private static int green = 240;

    private class EnterAction extends AbstractAction 
    {   
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) 
        {
            //System.out.println("Enter button is pressed");
            green -= 5;
            if (green <= 0) green = 0;
            setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, green, 255));
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: There's going to be a maximum of 5 panels. This eliminates the need to create a list maintain active panels.

Comment: *"I am trying to launch multiple JFrames"* See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556)

Comment: +1 for [`Action`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html).

Comment: @AndrewThompson I am creating a model for something. I guess I can change the scope of my application. There's going to be a maximum of 5 windows that can be opened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead, create a `PanelColorModel` that holds the current color. Let interested panels register as a listener to this model, using one of the [observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) implementations suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3072979/230513). Then your [`Action`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) can update the model and listeners can react accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to define a `static` Color attribute, so every time you hit Enter every subpanel will have the same color. Something like:

```
static Color subpanelBackgroundColor; //Every instance will have this.
```

Comment: I don't think this is accurate. Even if all panels share a static `color` variable, there still needs to exist an event that calls setBackground for each panel.